# Find the area bounded by the curve using the change of variables in double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, jacobian

Here is the equation:

$$
\left(\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}\right)^5=\frac{\left(x^2y^2\right)}{c^4}
$$

I got the general idea but I don't know how to start solving it, therefore I would greatly appreciate if someone could solve and explain it here.

I am very limited on time since there's a lot of pressure from my other courses. Thus, I would really appreciate detailed explanation of how to approach and solve this equation. I am newbie in this sphere and I struggle with finding correct approaches.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi Rajahho. The way your other courses are going is not relevant here, so let's focus on your equation. What do mean you've "got the general idea"? Have you ever used change of variables in a double integral before? What approach have you tried?

Comment: I have not used change of variables in a double integral before. The idea is to use polar coordinates and also to find boundaries for the integral.